# Excel macro button to move up page errors at top

Tags: excel, button, excel-2007, vba

In Excel I have a button that moves the selected cell marker up the page by 20 places relative to the cell that you were originally on. It works fine until it gets to the top and then has an error.

I get that this is [most likely] due to it going out of range, so I tried to make an if else statement to solve it - I think because I'm not 100% familiar with the function names I can't find the right wording to say: 
if cell is out of range, make equal to 0,0 or something similar.

This is what I have so far; the only bit that does work is the else part of the statement:

```
Sub moveUp20()
    '
    ' Move Up 20 Macro
    '

    '
    If ActiveCell.Offset(-20, 0) <= Range(0, 0) Then
    ActiveCell.Select = Range(0, 0)
    Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(-20, 0).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

It is probably something simple as I'm not familiar with excel macro programming terms/semantics, so I would appreciate some help! Thanks! :)

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do? I mean why manually selecting the cells? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a long Excel spreadsheet, so I created the button as a quicker way to move up and down the page than scrolling, as 20 places moves the selected cell from one section to the other.
I should probably make clear that the contents of the cell doesn't change - it is basically moving the selected cell 'cursor' around

Comment: Why not set the scrolling of your mouse so that it scrolls the rows accordingly? You don't need vba code for this :)

Comment: +1! Didn't know you could do this neat little feature! Will have to explore that.

Comment: Control panel | Mouse | Scroll Lines at a time

Comment: ahh but I've created it now! Seems a shame to throw it all away and not know the answer... :P

Comment: The only negative to this is that it effects your whole system, no? So, I think if the solution needed is workbook specific (or program specific, even), it's not that well-suited, because it changes the settings for every environment you are in, even if you don't want that. Correct me if I am wrong, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub moveUp20()

If ActiveCell.Row > 20 Then 'if you are on row 21 or below

    ActiveCell.Offset(-20).Select

Else ' select row 1 of the current column you are on

    Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column).Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: works like a charm! thank you very much! :D :D :D
p.s. would vote up but I'm a newbie to site ;(

Comment: `would vote up but I'm a newbie to site ` + 1 @bladepanthera: I have done it for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

For the functionality that you want, The simplest is

```
Sub moveUp20()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveCell.Offset(-20).Select
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

If you want you can also explore the option of

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-20
```

Comment: +1 for multiple solutions and another interpretation of the OP